# functional scala: can't compile

Tags: scala

I have OO background and tried some functional scala code as blow, but why some compile while one doesn't:

```
 def fun(a: Int => Int) = a(1)

  def fun1(f: => Int => Int => Int) = {
    fun { a => fun { b => f(a)(b) } }
  }

  fun1(Int=>Int=>Int)   // it compiles but what's Int=>Int=>Int? it only define type, but no param name, how it work without compile error?
  fun1(Int=>Int=>1)  
  fun1(a=>b=>a+b)
  fun1(a=>b=>Int)  // why this has compile error while other doesn't, such as fun1(Int=>Int=>1?
```

And please also help me to understand the first 2 calls resulted in value of 1 but the third resulted in 2.

Comment: kindly tell me what you are trying to do? What you are essentially doing overhere is mapping one variable to another. I think you need to see maps in scala

Answer (score 3):

In your first two examples, `Int` is just the name of a parameter, so:

```
fun1(Int=>Int=>Int)
```

is the same as

```
fun1(a => a => a)
```

where the outer parameter is shadowed by the parameter to the inner function.

In your last example, since `Int` is not a parameter, it is taken to be `Int.type`, so your last example is effectively:

```
fun1(_ => _ => Int.type)
```

Since the function needs to return an `Int`, this does not type check since `Int.type` is not compatible with `Int`.

Comment: Thanks, I am surprised Int could be a name of a parameter, but that's the fact :). Could you please also help me understand the value of these calls?